# create grails project from Maven archetype

Tags: grails, groovy, maven-2, maven-archetype

When I try to create a Mavenized Grails 1.3.6 project using the archetype:

```
mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeGroupId=org.grails 
-DarchetypeArtifactId=grails-maven-archetype -DarchetypeVersion=1.3.6 
-DgroupId=example -DartifactId=my-app 
-DarchetypeRepository=http://repo1.maven.org/maven2
```

I get the error

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:2.0:generate
>   (default-cli) on project
>   standalone-pom: The desired archetype
>   does not exist
>   (org.grails:grails-maven-archetype:1.3.6)

I've checked [the repository](http://repo2.maven.org/maven2/org/grails/grails-maven-archetype/) and version 1.3.6 does exist. Moreover, if I replace version 1.3.6 in the command above with 1.3.2, it works.

Answer (score 1):

Run `mvn archetype:generate` (interactive mode) and select option 286

286: remote -> grails-maven-archetype (Maven archetype for Grails projects.)

In general, I've had way more troubles than solutions with maven archetypes :S.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what's going on with your particular configuration, but I ran the exact command you listed there and it built successfully.  Since I'm guessing this is related to your previous question about how to specify dependencies, I suspect that you care more about the contents of the pom file than actually figuring out what's going on with the archetype, I'll post the pom.xml file that the archetype generated for me.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>example</groupId>
  <artifactId>my-app</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <name>A custom grails project</name>
  <description>A custom grails project</description>
  <url>http://www.myorganization.org</url>

  <properties>
    <grails.version>1.3.6</grails.version>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.grails</groupId>
      <artifactId>grails-bootstrap</artifactId>
      <version>${grails.version}</version>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.codehaus.gpars</groupId>
          <artifactId>gpars</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.codehaus.gant</groupId>
          <artifactId>gant_groovy1.7</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.gparallelizer</groupId>
          <artifactId>GParallelizer</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.codehaus.gant</groupId>
          <artifactId>gant_groovy1.6</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.apache.ant</groupId>
          <artifactId>ant</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.apache.ant</groupId>
          <artifactId>ant-launcher</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.apache.ivy</groupId>
          <artifactId>ivy</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.grails</groupId>
      <artifactId>grails-crud</artifactId>
      <version>${grails.version}</version>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.grails</groupId>
          <artifactId>grails-docs</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.apache.ant</groupId>
          <artifactId>ant</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.apache.ant</groupId>
          <artifactId>ant-launcher</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>radeox</groupId>
          <artifactId>radeox</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>commons-digester</groupId>
          <artifactId>commons-digester</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
          <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>junit</groupId>
          <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.grails</groupId>
      <artifactId>grails-gorm</artifactId>
      <version>${grails.version}</version>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.apache.ant</groupId>
          <artifactId>ant</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.apache.ant</groupId>
          <artifactId>ant-launcher</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>commons-digester</groupId>
          <artifactId>commons-digester</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>junit</groupId>
          <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
          <artifactId>hibernate</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
          <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
          <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>antlr</groupId>
          <artifactId>antlr</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.grails</groupId>
      <artifactId>grails-test</artifactId>
      <version>${grails.version}</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
      <version>1.1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
      <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
      <version>1.1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Grails defaults to Ehache for the second-level Hibernate cache. -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-ehcache</artifactId>
      <version>3.3.1.GA</version>
        <exclusions>
          <!-- See http://www.slf4j.org/faq.html#IllegalAccessError -->
          <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
          </exclusion>

          <!-- We are pulling in ehcache-core below -->
          <exclusion>
            <groupId>net.sf.ehcache</groupId>
            <artifactId>ehcache</artifactId>
          </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>net.sf.ehcache</groupId>
      <artifactId>ehcache-core</artifactId>
      <version>1.7.1</version>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
          <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <!-- For ease of development and testing, we include the HSQLDB database. -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>hsqldb</groupId>
      <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
      <version>1.8.0.10</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Use Log4J for logging. This artifact also pulls in the Log4J JAR. -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
      <version>1.5.8</version>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
      <version>1.5.8</version>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Needed in the case of AOP usage -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
      <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
      <version>1.6.8</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
      <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
      <version>1.6.8</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
      <version>1.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
      <version>3.2.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-pool</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-pool</artifactId>
      <version>1.5.3</version>
    </dependency>

  </dependencies>

  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.16</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>

  <repositories>
      <!-- Required to get hold of javassist:javassist -->
    <repository>
      <id>jboss.org</id>
      <name>jboss.org</name>
      <url>http://repository.jboss.com/maven2/</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>

  <build>
    <pluginManagement />

    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.grails</groupId>
        <artifactId>grails-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${grails.version}</version>
        <extensions>true</extensions>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>init</goal>
              <goal>maven-clean</goal>
              <goal>validate</goal>
              <goal>config-directories</goal>
              <goal>maven-compile</goal>
              <goal>maven-test</goal>
              <goal>maven-war</goal>
              <goal>maven-functional-test</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>

      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.5</source>
          <target>1.5</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>tools</id>
      <activation>
        <property>
          <name>java.vendor</name>
          <value>Sun Microsystems Inc.</value>
        </property>
      </activation>
      <dependencies>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>com.sun</groupId>
          <artifactId>tools</artifactId>
          <version>${java.version}</version>
          <scope>system</scope>
          <systemPath>${java.home}/../lib/tools.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>
      </dependencies>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

New maven archetype for grails 2 will be available soon. See [MAVEN-162](http://jira.grails.org/browse/MAVEN-162?focusedCommentId=70323&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3acomment-tabpanel#comment-70323)